# How, when, and where did the very first life in the universe exist/formed

Tags: life-history, astrobiology

Do we know about the very first life, how it is formed? or from where it originated in the universe?
How life is fromed in our planet earth??
Life require conditions for survival or it can create favorable conditions

Comment: To answer all your question: no.

Comment: We've never found life except on earth,  so as far as we know, it originated here. However, there are numerous theories about how.